# Reputation doesn't fall below 1

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've noticed a certain behavior in the **reputation** of any user. More often than not, there are many new users joining `SO` just to ask some very basic questions, **without trying** anything.

My questions is:-

When such questions are asked, we generally **downvote** that question to say that no effort was shown by the asked, but I've often noticed that the reputation of that **user** never falls below **1**. Is **1** some kind of magic number, here at SO or say, at the all **StackExchange** sites?

Comment: The minimum reputation any user can have is 1. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work (Deleted my answer, because I flagged the question as duplicate of the reference in this comment. =)

Comment: In this case, Toon's answer is somewhat better because it gives an explanation of *why*, so I'll keep mine deleted. Even if that answer is in the duplicate. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum reputation is 1.

The reason behind this is psychological. A reputation of 0 or lower is not good for self esteem.